# Limiting file size in Twisted FTP server

Tags: python, ftp, twisted

I am trying to implement an FTP server using twisted that limits the size of the uploaded file. Ideally this would happen before the transfer starts, but it is not really a problem if it exits gracefully during the transfer if it is too large.

I have started from the very basic ftpserver.py and slowly been pulling in more of the underlying classes from ftp.py to get down to the innards.

Current code below, please excuse the 'hack-and-slash' style employed until I can get it working.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPFactory, FTPShell, FTPAnonymousShell, IFTPShell
from twisted.cred.portal import Portal
from twisted.cred.checkers import AllowAnonymousAccess
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from twisted.python import filepath, failure

class FileConsumer1(object):
    def __init__(self, fObj):
        self.fObj = fObj

    def registerProducer(self, producer, streaming):
        self.producer = producer
        assert streaming

    def unregisterProducer(self):
        self.producer = None
        self.fObj.close()

    def write(self, bytes):
        size = os.fstat(self.fObj.fileno()).st_size + len(bytes)
        if size > 10:
            raise Exception("File too large") # WHAT GOES HERE?
        self.fObj.write(bytes)

class FileWriter1(object):
    def __init__(self, fObj):
        self.fObj = fObj
        self._receive = False

    def receive(self):
        assert not self._receive, "Can only call IWriteFile.receive *once* per instance"
        self._receive = True
        return defer.succeed(FileConsumer1(self.fObj))

    def close(self):
        return defer.succeed(None)

class FTPShell1(FTPShell):
    def openForWriting(self, path):

        p = self._path(path)
        if p.isdir():
            return defer.fail(IsADirectoryError(path))
        try:
            fObj = p.open('w')
        except (IOError, OSError), e:
            return errnoToFailure(e.errno, path)
        except:
            return defer.fail()
        return defer.succeed(FileWriter1(fObj))

class FTPRealm1(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.path = filepath.FilePath(root)

    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        avatar = FTPShell1(self.path)
        return (IFTPShell, avatar, getattr(avatar, 'logout', lambda: None))

p = Portal(FTPRealm1('./'), [ AllowAnonymousAccess() ])

f = FTPFactory(p)

reactor.listenTCP(4021, f)
reactor.run()
```

clearly the check if size > 10 will be bigger, but how should a be indicating there's a problem at this point? As it stands, twisted catches that exception, but it's not very elegant. As far as I can see from examination of ftp.py there's nothing obvious I can return here. Can I pass down a deferred in some way? How should I be closing down the transfer elegantly?

Thanks,

Here's a revised version

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

from zope.interface import Interface, implements

from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPFactory, FTPShell, FTPAnonymousShell, IFTPShell, IWriteFile    , BaseFTPRealm, FTPCmdError, EXCEEDED_STORAGE_ALLOC
from twisted.cred.portal import Portal
from twisted.cred.checkers import AllowAnonymousAccess
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer, interfaces
from twisted.python import filepath

class ExceededStorageAllocError(FTPCmdError):
    errorCode = EXCEEDED_STORAGE_ALLOC

class FileConsumer(object):
    implements(interfaces.IConsumer)
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ""
        self.error = None

    def registerProducer(self, producer, streaming):
        self.producer = producer
        assert streaming

    def unregisterProducer(self):
        if self.producer:
            self.producer.stopProducing()
        self.producer = None

    def write(self, bytes):
        self.data += bytes
        if len(self.data) > 10:
            self.unregisterProducer()
            self.error = ExceededStorageAllocError()

class FileWriter(object):
    implements(IWriteFile)
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def receive(self):
        self.consumer = FileConsumer()
        return defer.succeed(self.consumer)

    def close(self):
        if self.consumer.error:
            return defer.fail(self.consumer.error)
        try:
            f = self.path.open('w')
        except (IOError, OSError), e:
            return errnoToFailure(e.errno, path)
        f.write(self.consumer.data)
        return defer.succeed(None)

class FTPShell1(FTPShell):
    makeDirectory = FTPAnonymousShell.makeDirectory
    removeDirectory = FTPAnonymousShell.removeDirectory
    def openForWriting(self, path):
        p = self._path(path)
        if p.isdir():
            return defer.fail(IsADirectoryError(path))
        return defer.succeed(FileWriter(p))

class FTPRealm1(BaseFTPRealm):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        avatar = FTPShell1(filepath.FilePath(self.root))
        return (IFTPShell, avatar, getattr(avatar, 'logout', lambda: None))

p = Portal(FTPRealm1('./'), [ AllowAnonymousAccess() ])

f = FTPFactory(p)

reactor.listenTCP(4021, f)
reactor.run()
```

which accumulates the received data within the FileConsumer() then aborts if the file is too long. the close() method of the FileWriter() then either reports that error or writes the complete buffer to the file.

The only real issue I'm having with this is that when run, the exception is displayed on the server:

```
Unexpected error received during transfer:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: __main__.ExceededStorageAllocError:
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick disclaimer, I'm very bad with Twisted's producer/consumer model, so this may not work. As always, I'm not responsible if things blow up ;)

You seem to be on the correct path so pat yourself on the back for that. I think if you call `unregisterProducer` when a file is too large, the file should stop consuming. You may also need to call `self.producer.stopProducing()`, but don't quote me on that.

```
def unregisterProducer(self):
    self.producer.stopProducing()
    self.fObj.close()

def write(self, bytes):
    size = os.fstat(self.fObj.fileno()).st_size + len(bytes)
    if size > 10:
        self.unregisterConsumer()
        # log statements would go here
        # do some clean up too
    self.fObj.write(bytes)
```

If my mental code Python interpreter is correct, this should simply just stop consuming the file. As far as what you should return to the client, you're going to have to read the RFC about FTP to figure that out.

**PS**

As tedious as it may seem, please use the `@implementor` decorators. Most times you'll be fine, but there may be instances where unexpected trace backs appear.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the ideas, although I've used twisted for a while now, this is the first time I've come in contact with the producer/consumer model. I tried your suggestion, the FileConsumer1() class hasn't got the unregisterCosumer() method - do you mean unregisterProducer() ?

Comment: Whoops, yes I meant `unregisterProducer`. Edited the answer as well.

Comment: See my second version for a revised implementation using your suggestion which is working reasonable well and definitely stops the transfer when requested.

Comment: To handle the unexpected error, you might be able to trap the exception by chaining errbacks to `defer.succeed(self.consumer)`. I should really try to actually run your code ;) I haven't got the most time in the world these days unfortunately